# Macro send email, change 'from' Display Name but NOT email address

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server

I have this:

```
.SentOnBehalfOfName = """Customer Service"" <customerservice@testing.test>"
```

the name "Customer Service" is officially associated with the email address. I'd like to change that display name to something else but keep using the same email address like this:

```
.SentOnBehalfOfName = """ABC Event CS"" <customerservice@testing.test>"
```

or

```
.SentOnBehalfOfName = """XYZ Event CS"" <customerservice@testing.test>"
```

But it always uses the default display name instead of the one I specify. Is it possible to achieve this in some way?

Comment: You could try creating 2 contacts in Outlook that have that same email address but different names.

Comment: Thanks, @GregViers! I have hundreds of events to deal with so I'm trying to change it dynamically based on the event name, hence my need as described.

Comment: Are you trying to control how it appears to the recipient?

Comment: @GregViers Yes, please

Comment: This will depend on their own clients. I believe Exchange recipients will always see the real name of the sender, for example. This requires more Outlook / Exchange expertise. I'm going to add some other tags to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange always uses the default name and the primary SMTP address when sending. If you want to change the display name and/or select one of the proxy addresses from a particular mailbox, sending through SMTP is the only option if you need to do that programmatically. In case of an end user, you can use a product like [Proxy Manager](http://www.dimastr.com/proxyman/) (I am its author).

Comment: thank you, @dmitry-streblechenko, I will check it out.